# Is the composition relationship correct between a class and an enumeration?

Tags: class, uml, enumeration, composition

Because the unique instances of an enumeration lives during all the lifecycle of the application, I can say that **there will be no composition relationship** between a class and an enumeration.

[image]

Is what I say correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is simply contra-dictionary/nonsense. An enum is just one out of many. A composition is (as the name says) composed of multiple things. What you need here is a simple dependency which goes from `MyClass` to `MyEnum`. Not more.

Comment: I am absolutely agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I think simple Association relationship is enough. Correct me if I'm wrong, MyClass does not depend on MyEnum. It contains reference to enum class. Depending on your case it may or may not contain enum instance. I'd go with something like this

[image]

I mean we are talking about UML releationship types, thus association is more fitting.